# Overriding an instance method without inheritance in PHP?

Tags: php

Ok, i know that probably this is not possible, but i'll give it a try. Maybe my knowledge is not so good. Please don't downvote, this is just for curiosity and this maybe due to a poor OO design.

Assume that class definition for `A` is:

```
class A
{
    public function build()
    {
        $data = $this->fetchData();
        ...
    }

    public function fetchData()
    {
        // Database eavy query
        return $this->repository->fetchDataForCharting();
    }
}
```

And then, without using a good and decent OO design, you create class `B` which is going to use `fetchDataForCharting` from the repository, for doing some other different calculations:

```
class B
{
    public $data;

    public function getMonthlyLimit()
    {
        // Database eavy query
        $data = $this->getData();
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return isset($this->data) ? $this->data :
            $this->repository->fetchDataForCharting();
    }
}
```

Sometimes you need only `A`, sometimes you need only `B`, sometimes both. Is there any way of overriding `fetchData` at runtime? I mean someting like `$.extend()` in jQuery:

```
$b = new B();
$b->getMonthlyLimit(); // $b->data filled

$a = new A();

// Override fetchData
$a = extend($a, 'fetchData', function() use($b) { return $b->data; });

$a->build(); // Just 1 query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper way to modify/replace/add a class method.

The [`runkit`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension has [`runkit_method_redefine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php) and [`runkit_method_add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-add.php) but both are experimental and ugly (they take a code string, not a Closure object like your anonymous function is).

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear to me what you are trying to do, but in PHP you can have calss B extend class A by writing the class B declaration as so:

```
Class B extends Class A {
   ...
}
```

You can the override the fetchData function within Class B like

```
public function fetchData {
    // do something different than in class A
}
```

Or

```
public function fetchData {
    // execute the Class A functionality first
    parent::fetchData();

    // now do something in addition to what is in Class A functionality
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course I know. But think about at A and B as separate object with different meanings, that is not part of inheritance...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The closest you can get to exactly what you are asking is something like:

```
class A
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->bar = function()
    {
    };
  }

  public function foo()
  {
    $bar = $this->bar;
    $bar();
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->bar = function()
{
  // override
};
$a->foo();
```

Requires PHP 5.4 for `$this` support. But keep in mind that people do that sort of thing in JavaScript because it doesn't have "real" object oriented programming. You shouldn't try to emulate JavaScript, Ruby, Python, etc, just for the sake of doing it.

To be clear: in PHP, inheritance or composition or dependency injection is probably the proper way to go about what you are trying to do. (The above hack is definitely *not* what you should be doing.)